# Cleaning posts with omploader.org images

Tags: support, images, clean-up

#### 2019: Complete

All the posts which contain http://omploader.org have been cleaned up and most of them are closed, since the links gave to the post lots of details.

---

#### 2017: Request

http://omploader.org is apparently long dead. Yet, we have about **[40 posts to clean](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aomploader)** still using images hosted on it.

That shouldn't be too hard to remove all the links or eventually delete some posts. Help is welcome.

Comment: Use the internet archive to grab the originals: `http://web.archive.org/web/*/stackoverflow.com/questions/<question-id>/<question-title>` and / or `http://web.archive.org/web/*/omploader.org/<image-code>`. Not all images have made it there.

Comment: Bwhah, all the ones I tried so far are gone, all the archive has is the 404 error (as of 2015-ish).

Comment: Are [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887734/why-my-code-show-messy-code) worth editing? It makes no sense to me and I  don't know how I'd re-word it other than replacing the dead links with [IMAGE MISSING].

Comment: Thanks for fixing that BSMP "questions like this" linked post (whoever did that). It was worth the effort.

Comment: @PaulWratt that linked one got fixed and closed by the same person.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've started cleaning posts with omploader.org images. As [*@BSMP*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355753/cleaning-posts-with-omploader-org-images/355764#comment508553_355753) pointed out, several questions containing links to omploader.org are *only* linking to images. There are many examples ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703051/how-to-set-inbound-mail-for-google-app-engine), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988553/what-is-useful-of-os-environ-in-google-app-engine-why-google-use-os-environ-so), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626720/how-to-change-format-1-to-format-2), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091952/how-to-make-a-rss-for-my-sites-info-on-gae)). I noticed there are [answers as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026402/open-source-file-upload-distribution-server-like-rapidshare/6026480#6026480).

In my opinion, those questions/answers should not be edited but *deleted* as they are not understandable anymore.

Comment: @BhargavRao, what about deleting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286201/facebook-content-only-need-this-script as unsalvageable?

Answer (score -1):

Everything pre-2012 on [Internet Archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Archive) is good, and everything after that is a placeholder image, so there was never a chance of fixing most Stack Overflow posts at the time of this question (August 2017).